# mySQL INSERT INTO query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert 2 variables into my database. PHP looks like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` 
        (`field1`, 
         `field2`) 
        VALUES ('".$field1."','".$field2."') ";
```

However, when I try to run it, like so:

```
if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
}
```

It doesnt add to the database, and i get this error:
`mysqli_query()` expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in index.php on line 56.
 BTW my connection works fine, its not to do with that, but here it is anyway

```
$connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('Database connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: share your $connection ?

Comment: Your connection object seems to be null.

Comment: Use parameters instead of stuffing the values into the query.  Not only is putting the values in the string dangerous (SQL injection), but it can also cause unexpected syntax errors.

Comment: use `$connection = mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);` ?

Comment: Im a noob what does that mean in english lol @GordonLinoff

Comment: @jitendrapurohit its not the connection, it worked for other queries.

Comment: then may be your `$connection` gets modified in between. Can you share your code ?

Comment: As you already connection db name no need to use \`database\`.\`table\` just use \`table\`

Comment: @Binyamin Translation: Your sql code is vunerable if you dont specify parameters for values input by users. Someone could inject code into your database maliciously. Read up on SQL injection [and this page](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) on specific documentation about how to protect your database when using php

Comment: @Binyamin You're not using this with a custom function by any chance, are you? There isn't enough code to support the question. Plus, you did properly assign those constants and for the right db etc., right? and/or, including/requiring a file for the connection?

Comment: @Binyamin ping me when you want help from me.

Comment: I would just delete the question, and immerse yourself in reading for a few days. And some Led Zeppelin music

Comment: @Drew one cannot delete a question once there are multiple answers.

Comment: @Binyamin if one of the answers did help you out please select the one to be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open up a DB connection and query it use the following code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ('".$field1."', '".$field2."')";

// Perform queries 
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have set the connection correctly. 
As you are getting - "mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in index.php on line 56." and your first parameter to this function must be the connection variable.

Please see the follow

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ('".$field1."', '".$field2."')";
// Perform queries 
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a connection object, and are using a procedural style

Use `$connection->query($sql);`